# 2007 VW Jetta - Key won't turn - Steering wheel loose - Stuck in park

Tags: vw, car, repair, jetta

The vehicle has done this a number of times until finally now, the key won't turn at all.

What parts do I need, and do I need to make sure the new part is ''paired'' to our existing key/fob?

Thank you so much